# Error in executing Oozie workflow with Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I have written a Sqoop import script to import data from teradata to hive.
It's working fine when I run it from command line ,but when I put it in shell script and try to execute through oozie workflow I get the below error

```
`[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-shell] **Launcher ERROR,  reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain],** exit code [1]
2015-04-02 08:50:55,440  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-shell] end executor for wf action 0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W
2015-04-02 08:50:55,459  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-shell] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2015-04-02 08:50:55,505  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail] Start action [0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-04-02 08:50:55,505  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action status=DONE
2015-04-02 08:50:55,505  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action updated in DB!
2015-04-02 08:50:55,522  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W@fail] end executor for wf action 0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W
2015-04-02 08:50:55,556  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[qjdht93] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-shell-wf] JOB[0000069-150114201015959-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] **E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100**`
```

Below is my workflow.xml

```
`<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.3' name='sqoop-shell-wf'>
<start to='sqoop-shell' />
<action name='sqoop-shell'>
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
       <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
    <exec>Sqoopscript.sh</exec>
    <file>Sqoopscript.sh#script.sh</file>
</shell>
<ok to="end" />
<error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
<message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
```

Map reduce logs

```
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/janusclient.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/janusclient     .jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aster-  networking.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aster-networking.jar (Permission  denied)  
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs-api-loader.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs-api-loader.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aftp.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aftp.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs.jar (Permission denied)
Note: /tmp/sqoop yarn/compile/f3aca99f37fa19e505b47bab1499bf5d/EXT_EVNT_ERR_ARC.java uses or  overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class   [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
che.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - **Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:/user/yarn**`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a shell action, when you can/should be using the Sqoop action. There are several jars which need to be included when running Sqoop jobs. Most of them are included in the oozie sharelib. Here's an example workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="sqoop-to-hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="sqoop2hive"/>
    <action name="sqoop2hive">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop --username sqoop --password sqoop --table test --hive-import --hive-table test</command>
            <archive>/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar#mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar</archive>
            <file>/tmp/hive-site.xml#hive-site.xml</file>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I recommend following a [guide](http://ingest.tips/2014/11/27/how-to-oozie-sqoop-hive/) on how to use oozie and sqoop.

Comment: Hey Thanks!!..actually i need to write sqoop command inside shell only as 'll be passing parameter file to shell which will contain information required by sqoop like (IP,tablenamee,DBname) etc. then cleaning the hdfs directories and doing error handling

Comment: Hi changed my workflow.xml as suggeested by you but getting same error "Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], main() threw exception"

Comment: You probably need to specify oozie.use.system.libpath=true in your job.properties.

Comment: I can see the imported data in HDFS but oozie-sqoop job is not able to move it to Hive table

Comment: I have specified oozie.use.system.libpath=true in my job.properties file

Comment: I see so you're beyond your previous exception... Moving the data into hive is a bit tricky. Let's move this to private chat or post a question on the user@sqoop.apache.org mailing list.

Comment: I have updated my question with MR logs of the job..Can you now please suggest something? sqoop.hive.HiveImport - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:/user/yarn
why it is referring to this dir?